# Unexpected token in mysql query in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to run the following `MySQL` command in `PHPMyAdmin` to save having to download the file and upload it again.

The values I'm looking to change are dates in `dd/mm/yy` format to `dd.mm.yy` format.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, '/', '.')
WHERE meta_key = 'arrivaldate'
```

This is throwing up the following error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Thanks

Comment: `arrivaldate` I'm sure that is not the column of `wp_postmeta` table.

Comment: You haven't posted the structure of the table nor the complete error.

Comment: can you send a proof screenshot of the query you try to run on phpMyAdmin

Comment: It seems the suggestion from @Alex worked however, I had been using the simulator to check the query. When i simply clicked Go it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/879b5/1

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, '/', '.')
WHERE meta_key = 'arrivaldate'
```

Comment: youve got the idea of what Im looking to do but the error Im still getting is now this - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: sorry but I have no your MariaDB server installed, and you did not provide your table schema.

Comment: Sorry i should have been clearer. Thanks for the help. It seems to have worked, but it would not work when I used the simulator. Strange